# Trouble getting a (stripped) DLL to work with a C++ console app

Tags: c++, windows, dll, dllimport

I have a project to make an oldish (stripped, non-Com) DLL work in a new C++ console app. I've tried several things:

- Import a new reference from the Visual Studio console ... this doesn't work (apparently) because it's a non-COM thing ... 'browse' shows nothing in both Visual Studio 2017 and 2019.

  - use dumpbin and lib to create a lib from the DLL; dumpbin worked but lib gets a bunch of warnings:

```
LNK4017: statement not supported for the target platform: ignored
```

... and produces an apparently blank library.

Tried cygwin tools ... which don't work with stripped DLLs but otherwise look lovely ...

Questions:

1. Is this a waste of time? The vendor is supporting C# exclusively these days but the guy I'm working with is a C++ guy from way back and wants this if it's doable.

   2. If there's some easy way to do this, what is it please? I'm fully Linux/Cygwin/Msys2 capable if some of those toolkits will do this. I've been working for several hours on this today already.

Thanks much ...

Comment: If all else fails, there's `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`. Do you still have any headers with function prototypes for said DLL?

Comment: Yes, I created a header file from a document I found on the vendor's website.